# Book about boy with superpowers

Tags: story-identification

There’s a book I read about a boy that has superpowers he didn’t know about, but then he went somewhere (I can’t remember I think it was like some camp with his high school). He goes into a forest after hearing a cry, then sees a man helping a deer, I think lifting its feet out of twigs in the ground that it's stuck in. He then goes to the man's house on the mountain and then finds out he has superpowers. Then, a pop star comes and he chooses the boy to go mountain climbing with him. Can't remember what happened in that part.

Then he goes to his parents, but they moved somewhere (I think Egypt), and they say they have powers too. Then, he goes to some superpower academy and makes friends, but soon finds out that his mum is in danger or was ill. He tries to save her from the pop star, but the ground swallows his parents (or at least he thinks it does). He fights the pop star and the bad people, and I think there was a president somewhere or like some people who didn't have powers. Then, he finds out his parents didn’t die.

Comment: Was this boy in elementary school? High school? And how is the man helping the deer?

Comment: I can’t remember. I think high school. The man was helping the deers feet out of twigs that were stuck in the ground.

Comment: I really ought to have linked you to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question. It's got more prompts to help you figure out more details.

Comment: Like, when did you read this? How long was it? Did it seem like it was targeted to kids, adults, a particular social group? Was it in English? If a physical books, was it a paperback or a hardback? If electronics, was it a webpage? Kindle? EPub? Were superpowers something that it was known people could have? Am I correct that the "he" in "he has superpowers" refers to the boy? Or to the man who helped the deer? Do you remember what sort of music the pop star did? Was it known that he had powers before the boy ran into him?

Comment: I probably read like a year ago. I think not young kids but like 10 yrs and above. It was in English. It was paperback. No only a few people had the superpowers and they went to a superpower academy. Yes it refers to the boy but the man also has powers. Can’t remember what sort of music the pop star did. Yes the pop star knew he already had powers also the man helping the deer knew that he had powers himself.